# How can I get Processing IDE to exit gracefully on runtime Java errors?

Tags: java, macos, ide, runtime-error, processing

...other than wrapping everything in try..catch blocks?

I'm running Processing 3 on OSX Sierra. Every single time there's a silly runtime error, you get the spinning beachball and have to force-quit the applet (CMD+Opt+Esc). This is nuts: is there no more convenient way to have the Processing IDE handle these kinds of errors (eg: just shutdown the running applet and display the error message in the console log?)

Here's an example of such code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.color.*;

void setup(){
  Color A = new Color(255, 0, 0);
  ColorSpace CIELab = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab);
  println(A);
  println(A.getComponents(CIELab, null));
  noLoop();
}
```

It's just a test of some colour conversion, and (in case you didn't know), Java hasn't actually implemented `ColorSpace.TYPE_Lab` and it throws an "Unknown ColorSpace" error. Should be pretty harmless. No race condition here, nothing untoward, just an unimplemented abstract class. Shouldn't really warrant crashing the app and making me force-quit...

Maybe I'm just using the wrong mode, or there's a Preference I need to set?

Or does everyone who uses Processing play the CMD-Opt-Esc game all the time and just sucks it up?

Comment: Do you have an example of code that causes this error?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your problem Tom, your code fails just fine on my processing (3.2.3) on Sierra with an error and no crash of the IDE. And usually runtime errors do fail just fine. Problems like the one you report usually happen if you try to print too many things to the console (like a huge loop that prints in the draw() method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations such as these, you can usually just hit the "Stop" button on your Processing IDE, and you should be able to go on your way happily.

The big exception to this is if you're in `fullScreen()` mode, in which case you have no choice but to apply the Vulcan Death Grip and CMD+Opt+Esc.